# Como genero un volcado de SQL nombrándolo con la fecha actual

Tags: sql, cmd, .bat

Estoy programando un script para generar un volcado de BD, pero quiero que el nombre del archivo tenga la fecha del dia en el que se ejecuta (La ruta xampp2 es correcta,asi se llama mi carpeta)

```
@echo off
cd C:\xampp2\mysql\bin
mysqldump -u root -p --routines Inventario> C:\Users\JAIR\Desktop\volcadosSQL\%DATE%.sql
pause
exit
```

Estoy llamando a la variable `%DATE%` ,cuando ejecuto el script me muestra la siguiente salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sim embargo cuando manejo el comando con un nombre estatico, como por ejemplo:

```
@echo off
cd C:\xampp2\mysql\bin
mysqldump -u root -p --routines Inventario> C:\Users\JAIR\Desktop\volcadosSQL\respaldo.sql
pause
exit
```

Se ejecuta sin problema, como puedo manejar la variable %DATE% para que esta genere el `.sql`

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Ya intentaste poner %date% en miniscula?

Comment: Hola, lo acabo de intentar y obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: Revisa la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script)
Ahí declaran una variable, esa la podrias usar.
otra opcion sería hacer una variable que con la ruta completa y ver que sucede

Comment: Ya funciono muchas gracias, en efecto ahi estaba las respuesta muchas gracias